# How to fix microphone that sometimes has wrong volume, other times doesn't work at all?

Tags: sound, microphone

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04. I have had mic problems since 10.04. At times my mic level is just really low and other times it just doesn't work at all. I am using a Gateway M-Series. How can I get it working all the time and at the right level?

Answer (score 1):

Install [gnome-alsamixer [image: Install gnome-alsamixer]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-alsamixer) and select the *mic boost* option in it.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. I have already tried that method. But in my Gnome Alsa Mixer, there is no option for that.

Comment: I have had really good experience with the gnome-alsamixer. It gives me total control over the mic volume. The mixer seems to automatically mute the volume for rear mic, but I think that is just a convenience feature. But when I need the mic up, it is very reliable. You just have to adjust the volume.